# Windows Phone 8 camera - PhotoCaptureDevice in Nokia - 920

Tags: c#, xaml, camera, windows-phone-8

I have developed the Camera application by using the PhotoCaptureDevice in the Windows Phone 8. I am able to run this application in the Nokia 820. But i don't have 920 device to test this app. But one of my user says that , this app does not run in Nokia 920 device. The VideoBrush that is supposed to show the camera viewfinder is blank. Can you please any one help me on this ?. If possible can you please test this in 920 device.

Exact code snippet that i use in the InitializeCamera

```
private static async Task InitializeCamera()
        {
            PhotoCaptureDevice d = null;

            try
            {
                Windows.Foundation.Size initialResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
                Windows.Foundation.Size previewResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
                Windows.Foundation.Size captureResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);


                if (PhotoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Back))
                {
                    d = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, initialResolution);

                    await d.SetPreviewResolutionAsync(previewResolution);
                    await d.SetCaptureResolutionAsync(captureResolution);

                    d.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation,
                                  d.SensorLocation == CameraSensorLocation.Back ?
                                  d.SensorRotationInDegrees : -d.SensorRotationInDegrees);
                    _device = d;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted your code into a project and it worked fine for me on my Lumia 920.  I'm not sure if you have this in another part of code, but the only thing I did in addition was add this after the the "_device = d;" line:

```
                   ViewfinderBrush.SetSource(_device);
```

With XAML like this:

```
        <Rectangle x:Name="Viewfinder">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="ViewfinderBrush"  />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

One thing to note is the SetSource must be after the Device has initialized (ie, after OpenAsync).  If you set it before, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Got an HTC8X or I'd help you out.
Why don't you just request a loaner 920 from Nokia?  http://blog.dvlup.com/2012/11/20/three-ways-dvlup-can-get-you-a-developer-handset/ .  You get to keep it for about two weeks.